# Compare row with every other row in the table except the previous ones, how can I do this?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I write a query that returns the sum of ages for a pair of people. I want to compare the current row with every other rows in the database except the previous ones? For example, I have a Person table and the table has 3 records (In my real table, I have a lot more). Person 1's age should be compared with Person 2 and Person 3 and Person 2 should be compared with Person 3. How can I accomplish this in query form?

Comment: What does "compare" mean?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: It's actually not a compare, but I need to take a pair of person to get two ages, and then i apply these two ages in a sum formula

Comment: could you share the details of the table

Comment: person => idperson, age, name

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a row with all the values using an inequality `join`:

```
select p1.*, p2.*
from person p1 join
     person p2
     on p1.id < p2.id;
```

Comment: this would compare p1 with p2 and p3?.

Comment: This compares [person.id =1 with person.id =2, 3, 4, ...], [person.id = 2 with person.id =3, 4, ...] and so on. Last person.id will not be compared this way as there is no further person.id. This should satisfy the matching/joining requirement asked.

Comment: @k4m yes, it makes sense, although the question says that OP wants to "sum of ages for a pair of people". So i assumed it was group of 2 that OP wants to compare

Comment: Well, it seemed the main challenge was the join logic. since that's been accomplished, the rest should be a simple sum maybe like this 

`select p1.id, (p1.age + p2.age) TotalAge from .....` It all depends how the "sum" is defined, which is not clear in the question

Answer (score 0):

What @gordon-linoff wrote as an answer for the join was correct. It's just missing the total calculation. Here is how the total can be accomplished (I had to open a new answer since I couldn't edit Gordon's answer, sorry):

```
SELECT 
    p1.id
    , p1.name
    , p2.id
    , p2.name
    , (p1.age + p2.age) TotalAge
FROM 
    person p1 
    JOIN person p2  ON  p1.id < p2.id;
```

This compares [person.id =1 with person.id =2, 3, 4, ...], [person.id = 2 with person.id =3, 4, ...] and so on. The last p1.id will not be compared this way as there is no further p2.id greater (but that person will be included in all other comparisons as p2.id because it is larger than all others). This should satisfy the matching/joining requirement asked.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to do these kind of comparisons, its assumed that you have an order defined. In this case it appears to be person ID is the order.

You can use analytical function with a windowing clause to get the desired result.
You use `SUM` as the analytic function and consider the window of the rows between the next row all the way till the last row as per your order.

Thus the query becomes

```
WITH
    persons
    AS
        (SELECT 1 AS personid, 'Person 1' AS name, 23 AS age FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 2 AS personid, 'Person 2' AS name, 34 AS age FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 3 AS personid, 'Person 3' AS name, 30 AS age FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 4 AS personid, 'Person 4' AS name, 28 AS age FROM DUAL)
SELECT personid,
       name,
       SUM (age)
           OVER (ORDER BY personid ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
           AS subsequent_sum_age
FROM persons;
```

The `ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` is your windowing clause which tells Oracle which rows to consider for summation.

The result of this is

```
 PERSONID   NAME       AGE  SUBSEQUENT_SUM_AGE
   1        Person 1    23     92
   2        Person 2    34     58
   3        Person 3    30     28
   4        Person 4    28
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have much more that 4 person in my table, do i need to define a union for each person separately?

Comment: The WITH statement and union is for simulating a table with some rows in it. In this case persons is like a table with the rows and columns. Its just to demonstrate the query. Your actual query will not have it. Replace the `persons` in the actual query with your table name.